SMAPI positionInformation being ignored
I am implementing a SMAPI service for podcasts.
Following the documentation here
I have set my Item Type to track and am returning positionInformation with the getMediaUri call.
However Sonos ignores the position information and plays the track from the start every time.
getMetadata response:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns:getMetadataResponse>
      <ns:getMetadataResult>
        <ns:index>0</ns:index>
        <ns:count>41</ns:count>
        <ns:total>41</ns:total>
        <ns:mediaMetadata>
          <ns:id>track::123</ns:id>
          <ns:itemType>track</ns:itemType>
          <ns:title>Test track 1</ns:title>
          <ns:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns:mimeType>
          <ns:trackMetadata>
            <ns:artistId>A:123456</ns:artistId>
            <ns:artist>Test Artist</ns:artist>
            <ns:albumid>M:123456</ns:albumid>
            <ns:album>test Album</ns:album>
            <ns:duration>600</ns:duration>
            <ns:albumArtURI>http://example.com/images/aa/1.jpg</ns:albumArtURI>
            <ns:canSkip>false</ns:canSkip>
            <ns:canResume>true</ns:canResume>
            <ns:canAddToFavorites>false</ns:canAddToFavorites>
          </ns:trackMetadata>
        </ns:mediaMetadata>
...

getMediaUri response:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
  <s:Body>
    <ns:getMediaURIResponse>
      <ns:getMediaURIResult>https://my-sonos-service.com/testaudio.mp3</ns:getMediaURIResult>
      <ns:positionInformation>
        <ns:id>track::123</ns:id>
        <ns:index>0</ns:index>
        <ns:offsetMillis>30000</ns:offsetMillis>
      </ns:positionInformation>
    </ns:getMediaURIResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>



It seems that the issue was in the duration, the test track was longer in duration than the 600 seconds I manually typed.
After setting the duration to anything equal or longer than the track, the position information was followed by sonos.

Since you are implementing podcast support, please also refer to the documentation under https://docs.sonos.com/docs/add-podcasts
There is a <semanticType>episode.podcast</semanticType> which should be included alongside the <itemType>track</itemType> for episode types, and a <semanticType>podcast</semanticType> which should be included alongside <itemType>show</itemType> for podcast containers.
This typing discrepancy could be interfering with the resume behavior, and including the correct <semanticType>s will ensure your content appears and behaves correctly on Sonos. Please follow-up if the issue still persists!

Thanks, I've included the semanticType but the issue is still persisting.
